# Office 365 Public Website Search Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-scope, public-website

I'm building a public facing site in Office 365 SharePoint.

I added the search snippet in my master page and it works but it doesn't search the site pages only my lists and document libraries.

How do I make the public website search to search site pages only?

Answer (score 1):

The masterpage for the public website already comes with a search box, which you should reuse on your own masterpage. If I search for content using the existing masterpage or my own (based on the out-of-the-box one) I get the expected search result including not only documents and list item, but also pages.

Start by copying the masterpage on your public website and style the search box if needed, but don't add an unnecessary search component.

Comment: Can i get itto search pages only

Comment: @knox2 When searching you have the option to display web pages only, or implement a display template and replace the video search display template as an example...